# Why does this refresh command crash the app?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Heres all the lines associated with the refresh command

This is the main binding in the XAML code

```
RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
```

This is the ViewModel

```
async Task Refresh()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        await Task.Delay(2000);

        Note.Clear();

        var notes = await NoteService.GetNote();

        Note.AddRange(notes);

        IsBusy = false;

    }
```

And the method GetNote looks like this

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Note>> GetNote()
    {
        await Init();

        var note = await db.Table<Note>().ToListAsync();
        return note;
    }
```

There are other methods include Refresh command, and they do not crash whenever the Refresh part is excluded, hence I believe the issue is related with this refresh method. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: **Which line** causes the crash? Step through the code and/or comment out lines until you isolate it.

Comment: if you have code that is crashing the app, the first thing you should try is add a `try/catch` around it to **catch** the exception causing it.  Knowing which exception causes the crash is the first step towards fixing it

Comment: Ok so if I delete these two lines `var notes = await NoteService.GetNote(); Note.AddRange(notes);` the app doesn't crash but it also doesn't do its job, so maybe it is about the GetNote method? I will investigate further.

Comment: or you could take 30s to add a try/catch and get the actual exception causing the crash.  And/or step through the code in the debugger as Steve suggested.

Comment: Is this what I am looking for?    "JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetObjectClass called with pending exception android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 35:33. Can not find the object referenced by `NotePage`"

Comment: I found this : System.NullReferenceException
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Sorry I don't know all this stuff

Comment: There is a null object somewhere in that block of code.  Figure out which one it is.  NullRef is one of the most common c# errors and there are endless articles about how to track them down

Comment: Using break points I found out that after `var note = await db.Table<Note>().ToListAsync();` note stops being null and gets a value but after IsBusy is set to false the app crashes

Answer (score 1):

Is `Note` binded to a UI element, such as a ListView?

If so, you may have to ensure that UI-related actions such as `Note.AddRange(notes);` are executed in the Main UI thread:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
    var notes = await NoteService.GetNote();
    Note.AddRange(notes);
});
```

More details here: [Why use Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread() in a Xamarin application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206877/why-use-device-begininvokeonmainthread-in-a-xamarin-application)

Comment: I replaced it with `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Note.AddRange(notes); });` however the app still crashes whenever the Refresh method is used. Also, there is `ItemsSource="{Binding Note}"` under ListView. Deleting said binding stops the app from crashing but also as expected stops the app from doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Could you try putting `var notes = await NoteService.GetNote();` inside the main thread invocation as well? It's also possible that this needs to be executed in the main thread as well, depending on what that `db` variable is.